# How to download file from server in VS lightswitch

Tags: silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

for a VS Lightswitch Application, there is not any inbuilt support for printing. but we can create a .pdf file to server and make it available to VSLS client.

but i m unable to code for that logic.

can any body will help me

Regards,
Akhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/35/Saving-Files-To-File-System-With-LightSwitch-Uploading-Files.aspx) shows how to grab files from the file system in the Lightswitch app, then have the file downloaded.

You can change the code to get your pdf file instead then have it downloaded.